# Is there any way to download an app beyond Play Store?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I've published an app and I have a theoric doubt. In my google play administrator page, it shows me that my app was downloaded by 18 devices, but when I look at the google analytics, on the same period, I have over 100 devices.

I've looked for other links on Google, but every link that I found redirects to Google Play, so Google Play should count it. Is  there any way to download the app from google play, and then, get the apk?

The funniest part is that I didn't spread this app and when I look at the place of the users, it's from India, Sudan, etc..(I'm from Brazil, the other side of the world)..

Comment: I've looked for about more things and I found this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1759160 There is a guy that says "There is a trade embargo between the United States of America and countries deemed as "rogue countries" (Sudan, North Korea, Iran etc..). iTunes used to not work in Sudan either but I found a way to bypass it by using a vpn or proxy server. I used ultrasurf to get into the iTunes Store and it thought I was in California. Until America stops bullying our country this is the way things will have to be, ya habib. Sudanese Solidarity!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Apk can be downloaded from Google Play and than shared as file somewhere else. These downloaded apks are disributed commonly in these countries like India etc.

For example there is an extension to it for chrome https://lekensteyn.nl/apk-downloader/.

So I would say your Google Analytics data are valid.

Comment: So, should I be happy or sad? hahahaha What is the purppose? Why people just don't download it from google play, if their android devices looks original and ok? But it's a drag because my app on google play doesn't seem with too many downloads..

Comment: I think you should just accept this as a fact and don't be sad about it. I heard from few other developers that this is common practice for these countries. And their purpose? I don't know. Probably they are just used to download apps this way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to download the app from google play, and then, get the apk?

Sure. Copying the APK off of a device is not that difficult. In addition, software pirates bulk download pretty much everything uploaded to the Play Store and make it available from their own sites.